# Issue with check/uncheck Radio button based on condition using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to retrieve the value of ajax and it worked, but I try want to display input: radio if the condition is true then it will be checked, but no change in my script.
so if the value status = 1, then input: radio is checked and if the value status = 0 then it is not checked.

My Html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="status">Status</label>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-on btn-sm ">
        <input type="radio" value="0"  name="status" id="aktif" >Active</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-off btn-sm active">
        <input type="radio" value="1" name="status" id="deaktif" >Deactive</label>  
    </div>
</div>
```

My ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo site_url('edit')?>/" + id_user,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        $('[name="status"]').val(data.msg_activation);
        $('#edit').modal('show'); 

        if($('[name="status"]').val(data.status) === 1) {
            $('#aktif').prop('checked', true);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error ajax');
    }
});
```

Comment: `.val(data.status)` will set the value to the passed value, to get the value use `.val()`

Comment: Also are you trying to test only the checked value? Would help if you gave a better explanation of exactly what you are trying to check for

Comment: @Tushar, thanks it's true label but not Changed

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for your advice but I just have a problem that section

Comment: That really doesn't provide a proper explanation is the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `if` condition and try as below,

```
$('#aktif').prop('checked', data.status === 1);
```

Code

```
$.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo site_url('edit')?>/" + id_user,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        $('[name="status"]').val(data.msg_activation);
        $('#edit').modal('show'); 

        $('div.btn-group label.btn').removeClass('btn-on btn-off');

        $('#aktif').prop('checked', data.status === 1);
        $('#aktif').parent().addClass(data.status === 1 ? 'btn-on' ? 'btn-off');

        $('#deaktif').prop('checked', data.status === 0);
        $('#deaktif').parent().addClass(data.status === 0 ? 'btn-on' ? 'btn-off');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error ajax');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks @aruna, for checked I've found the answer, but how that label also changes??

Comment: this example [example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/irwandwiyanto/uttvjypt/) so if status = 1 `<label class="btn btn-default btn-on btn-sm ">' show

Comment: I assume you want to toggle the css classes `btn-on` and `btn-off` based on the selection. Please confirm.

Comment: yes true, so if status = 1 class = .btn-default.btn-on.active, and if not same class = .btn-default.btn-off.active

Comment: thank you so much it really helps, there is little that I change the script that you created and the results were unresolved issues.

Comment: @irwandwiyanto Great :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a further selector like this,

```
$('input[name="status"]').val(data.msg_activation);
```

to prevent the label also from getting changed